# dotnet publish and deploy with ftp Github Actions

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ftp, github-actions, dotnet-cli

I am trying to set up Github Actions to:
-build .net Core app
-test the app (unit tests)
-make a release (dotnet publish)
-deploy to ftp server

I am having some issues with the last step. I am using this action to deploy to ftp: https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action

It always deploys the whole repository instead of just the release files.

My workflow:

```
name: BuildAndTest

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Setup .NET Core
  uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
  with:
    dotnet-version: 3.1.101
- name: Install dependencies
  run: dotnet restore
- name: Build with dotnet
  run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
- name: Test
  run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal
- name: Publish
  run: dotnet publish MyApp.sln --configuration Release --framework netcoreapp3.1 --output ./publish --runtime win-x86  --self-contained true -p:PublishTrimmed=true -p:PublishSingleFile=true
- name: FTP Deploy
  uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.0.0
  with:
    # Deployment destination server & path. Formatted as protocol://domain.com:port/full/destination/path/
    ftp-server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
    # FTP account username
    ftp-username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
    # FTP account password
    ftp-password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
    # The local folder to copy, defaults to root project folder
    local-dir: /home/runner/work/MyApp/MyApp/publish/
```

local-dir is pointing at the directory i specified in the dotnet publish command

The workflow does not fail but is not transferring the correct files. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked FTP server log? What does it say about the files transferred?

Comment: I changed the dotnet publish command to this: dotnet publish --configuration Release --no-restore --output ./publish --self-contained true --runtime win-x86 -p:PublishTrimmed=true that helped me publishing the files to the correct directory. Next i used another ftp-action which suited my need better: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ftp-action

Comment: @AndersTofte thx I had the same issue and it has fixed my problem

Answer (score 4):

**Make it Simple!!** 
Change the publish command

```
- name: Publish
    run: dotnet publish -c Release --output ./Release
```

Then just send all those compiled files from Release folder `local-dir: ./Release/` without being worried about the home folder.

```
- name: FTP Deploy
  uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.0.0
  with:
    ........
    local-dir: ./Release/
```